# AWS Appflow - Salesforce OAUTH 2.0 JWT

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, salesforce, aws-secrets-manager, amazon-appflow

Below is the connector profile I am planning to create to support Salesforce OAUTH 2.0 authentication.

How I can store the Private Key(*.pem file) and Consumer Key(Salesforce supplied) to perform OAuth 2.0 implementation in clientCredentialsArn entry ? I attempted various trial method but it didn't help

```
aws appflow create-connector-profile \
--connector-profile-name salesforce-connector \
--connector-type Salesforce \
--kms-arn arn:aws:kms:$region:$account_id:key/$key_id \
--connection-mode Public \
--connector-profile-config '{
    "connectorProfileProperties": {
        "Salesforce": {
            "instanceUrl": "https://your-domain.my.salesforce.com",
            "isSandboxEnvironment": false
        }
    },
    "connectorProfileCredentials": {
        "Salesforce": {
            "oAuthRequest": {
                "authCode": $oauth_authorization_code,
                "redirectUri": $redirect_uri
            },
            "clientCredentialsArn": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:$region:$account:secret:$secret"
        }
    }
}
```